# How to validate maven proxy setting

Tags: eclipse, maven, proxy, maven-2

I am trying to setup a maven project in my client environment and facing the issue.

I want to know if there is any way validate the proxy settings of maven

I know the internet is behind the proxy and so I have updated the settings.xml with following settings. These values are not actual values.

```
<proxies>
    <proxy>
        <id>optional</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <username>proxyuser</username>
        <password>proxypass</password>
        <host>localhost</host>
        <port>8080</port>
    </proxy>
</proxies>
```

points to note.

- I don't have rights to check the exact proxy setting in internet or control panel
- I don't have write to download maven and run project from command line.
- I could only run project from eclipse.

The error I am getting in eclipse is

> apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved:

i have already tried following things

- force update the maven project in eclipse
- make sure that maven setting in eclipse is pointing to settings.xml file

Answer (score 0):

You can try -U flag. Just run follow command from eclipse

```
  mvn  -U verify
```

As described:

```
    -U --update-snapshots Forces a check for updated releases and snapshots on remote repositories
```

If it fails to connect remote repository you can guess that proxy or some proxy related setting is not set correctly.